# How can I access variable inside another function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this object and want to access the variable scrolled `var scrolled = 10;` from the `init` function within the `scrollDown` function.

I am having trouble accessing the variable. How can I achieve this?

```
// Summary Screen Functions
var summary = {
    init: function() {

        var scrolled = 0;

        $('.page-summary-action a').on('click', summary.continueToSummary);
        $('.scroll-down').on('click', summary.scrollDown);
        $('.scroll-up').on('click', summary.scrollUp);
    },

    scrollDown: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        scrolled = scrolled + 300;

        console.log('clicked');

        $(".data-cards").animate({
            scrollTop:  scrolled
        });
    },

    scrollUp: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('clicked');

        $(".data-cards").animate({
            scrollTop: 15
        });
    }
};

summary.init();
```

Comment: Put the variable outside of the `summary` object or make it a property of the `summary` object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Looks like you want the Revealing Module Pattern. Or you need to expose `scrolled` variable using `this.scrolled`, but then you need to initialise the object using `new`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jquery - Grab Variable from Another Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9676499/jquery-grab-variable-from-another-function)

Comment: They are 2 very different functions. Mine is using object literal @Sandman

Comment: can you provide me an example? @PeterMader

Comment: They are 2 very different functions. Mine is using object literal @FelixKling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var scrolled = 0; // Put the variable in an outer scope
var summary = {
    init: function() {
        // access "scrolled"
        scrolled = 0;
    },

    scrollDown: function(e) {
        // access "scrolled"
    },

    scrollUp: function(e) {
        // ...
    }
};

summary.init();
```

or

```js
var summary = {
    scrolled: 0, // Make it a property of the "summary" object
    init: function() {
        // access "scrolled"
        summary.scrolled = 0;
    },

    scrollDown: function(e) {
        // access "scrolled"
    },

    scrollUp: function(e) {
        // ...
    }
};

summary.init();
```

Comment: Thanks man! I liked the second answer, I wanted to keep things inside of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Following your question, you should use `this.scrolled` instead of var. An example would be

```
 var summary = {
    init: function() {
        this.scrolled = 20;
    },

    scrollDown: function(e) {
        console.log(this.scrolled);
    },

    scrollUp: function(e) {
        console.log(this.scrolled);
    }
 };   
 summary.init();
 summary.scrollDown();
```

to satisfy your curiosity, you should look up this link [How does the “this” keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work) and [Explanation from MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)